# how to change array name in .mat file using python

Tags: python, scipy

I am renaming '.mat' files. Unfortunately when I rename the file with os.rename or shutil.move the file name changes but the array name stays the same. How do I change the array name as well? Preferably w/o having to io.loadmat then io.savemat. Granted I will do if necessary.

For example, lets say initial filename was `xx.mat`

using code below I would change filename to `yy_xx.mat`

`shutil.move(os.path.join(f_dir, original_filename),os.path.join(f_dir_2, f"yy_{aug}"))`

Got the appropriate file name change to `yy_xx.mat`

but when I load the data I get

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Mon Jun  3 11:57:33 2019',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'xx.mat': array([1,2,3,4]}
```

For the rest of the code that this is in I need `xx.mat` to be the new filename `yy_xx.mat`.

thanks

Comment: A `.mat` file can have many arrays, with names that are unrelated to the file name.  They are the names of the variables in the MATLAB session.  When you `data=loadmat(...)`, you access the array with `myarray = data['xx.mat']` (or whatever name is used in the file.  You shouldn't need to change the array names on the file.

Comment: But if you must change the array names on the file, you'll need to `loadmat`, and then make a new file with `savemat` using the desired names.